# Vuex Mapping inside Getters

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I am new to vuex and working on the best way to store the data inside vuex.

I have an array of objects:

```js
teamData:[{
        name: 'team1',
        acronym: 't1',
        color1: '#hexcode1',
        color2: '#hexcode2',
    },
    {
        name: 'team2',
        acronym: 't2',
        color1: '#hexcode1',
        color2: '#hexcode2',
    },

]
```

I have set a getter to

```js
team1Name: (state) => state.teamData[0].name,
team1acronym: (state) => state.teamData[0].acronym,
```

is there a better way to map over this as the number of teams could change.

Looking to do a loop that will map over the length of the array and set the value that way

Answer (score 0):

I think you can just pass the team number as parameter like this :

```js
teamName: (state) => (teamNumber) => state.teamData[teamNumber].name,
teamAcronym: (state) => (teamNumber) => state.teamData[teamNumber].acronym,
```

Of course, this might need some check to see if the team exists like :

```js
teamName: (state) => (teamNumber) => state.teamData[teamNumber] ? state.teamData[teamNumber].name : ""
```

---

> Looking to do a loop that will map over the length of the array and set the value that way

I don't know if this is what you want but you can  return all names from your store using the `js` map function

Example

```js
teamNames: (state) => state.teamData.map(team => team.name)
```